# Android - Can we use flash file(.flv or .swf) to make a live wallpaper for an android device?

Tags: android, flash, live-wallpaper

I have tried searching internet for a sample which could guide me to use a flash file as a live wallpaper in my app.

May anyone explain what steps do i need to take to use it. If possible then please explain with some code snippets.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Whoever voted it down please provide a reason. Because i could not see a reason that why someone will vote it down. It is a good question which could help people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure AIR for android cannot be a live wallpaper because AIR for android is actually a runtime, and not a standalone app. the AIR for android runtime just doesn't have that feature.

That said, here is some helpful thoughts:
AIR for android is a bit of a resource hog at present (version 2.6) if you use it for a live wallpaper, it will (probably) cause significant battery drain.

Developing live wallpapers in java is not that hard. If you are used to actionscript 3, switching over to a java is pretty easy. 
Check out [Andengine](http://andengine.org) - it supports exporting to live wallpapers. You canexport all of your flash assets and recreate your app pretty easily.

Answer (score -7):

Most flash file movies get boring after one or two views at most and given that phones have limited battery life, why waste it on nonsense nobody really wants. Your users want to use the app and not be distracted by the "moving" background.

Comment: Read the question once again. I asked about live wallpapers not about an app. And as far as i know live wallpapers are all about moving backgrounds.

Comment: Not an answer to the specific question